# On Duplicate Key Error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check to see if there is a duplicate record and then either insert or update. I have made to_number field (which is a phone number) a UNIQUE field. There is a PRIMARY KEY "id" that is auto-increment. Not sure if this is what's causing the headache. Here is my code and then below that the error.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO DC**** (id, dcsrep, name, to_number, amount, date, digits, details)
VALUES ('', '$dcsrep', '$name', '$to_number', '$amount', '$date', '$digits', '$details') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dcsrep = values($dcsrep), name = values($name), to_number = values($to_number), amount = values($amount), date = values($date), digits = values($digits), details = values($details)";
```

> Error: INSERT INTO ***Auth (id, dcsrep, name, to_number, amount, date, digits, details) VALUES ('', 'notreal@notreal.com', 'Test Johnson', '+15555551212', '150.00', '2015-12-16', '1234', 'Testing again.') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dcsrep = values(notreal@notreal.com), name = values(Test Johnson), to_number = values(+15555551212), amount = values(150.00), date = values(2015-12-16), digits = values(1234), details = values(Testing again.)
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@notreal.com), name = values(Test Johnson), to_number = values(+15555551212),' at line 2

Comment: If `id` is autoincrement ---- don't try to set it to an empty space, don't try to set it at all

Comment: I took out the id in the insert and value portion and still getting the same error.

Comment: Does your insert not have quotes around the parameters being passed in to `VALUES`? e.g. `dcsrep = values('notreal@notreal.com')`

Comment: I added the quotes. Everything worked fine until I added the ON DUPLICATE KEY. Now the error is somewhere around - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''notreal@notreal.com'), name = values('Test Johnson'), to_number = values('+1' at line 2

Comment: The problem is in your `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. The data there should also be quoted: `values(notreal@notreal.com)` should read `values('notreal@notreal.com')`, etc.. Also look into prepared statements: Your code is a SQL injection hazard.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing. I went back and added quotes around the on duplicate key values, ie; dcsrep = values('$dcsrep'), to_number = values('$to_number') etc.

Comment: I'm trying to see if the to_number field, which is a phone number, in the database already exists, if so then update all the other info associated with that phone number, if not then insert the new row with all of that person's info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> You can use the VALUES(col_name) function in the UPDATE clause to refer to column values from the INSERT portion of the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement.

But you are not providing the column names, you are providing the values again.

So, either you provide the column name again:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dcsrep = values(dcsrep), ...
```

or you skip the `VALUES()` function and provide the value:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dcsrep='$dcsrep', ...
```

Note:

There is no reason to update all columns when you only want to update the phone number. If all other fields stay the same anyway, just update the column that holds the phone number.

Comment: Thanks! I know it's simple stuff but I'm still learning. All the help I receive here is much appreciated.

Comment: Actually I didn't know about the `VALUES()` function in this context myself until now. And I've been working with MySQL for more than 15 years ...